# how to get return code when using invoke-command against multiple computers?

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

i'm trying to know if my scipt was effectively executed on all the remote hosts when using invoke-command like this :

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName "test1","test2" -ScriptBlock {$env:computername}
```

when it runs interactively it's OK i can see error messages like this :

> - CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (test1:String) [], PSRemotingTransportException
> - FullyQualifiedErrorId : NetworkPathNotFound,PSSessionStateBroken

but how to do when running the script in 'batch mode' ?

I tried the try{} catch{} statement but it doesnt seem to work,

then I tried to handle the result in a variable, didnt work either :

```
PS>$result=Invoke-Command -ComputerName "test1","test2","rodc1" -ScriptBlock {$env:computername}

PS>$result
rodc1
```

I have ended up to use new-pssession for each host and test it like this

```
$computers=@("test1","test2","rodc1")
$computers|%{
    $s=new-PSSession -ComputerName $_
    if($s -eq $null){
        $errs +="$_ : cant connect to host `n<br/>"
    }
    else{
        $sess+=$s
    }
}

invoke-Command  -Session $sess -ScriptBlock {$env:computername} -asJob -jobName "test"
```

now, i can use $errs to know which computers failed

Is there a better/simplier way to do this ?
thank you

Comment: I just tried on my machine and your original version returns results from all machines:
C:\src\Main>Invoke-Command -ComputerName "test1-fs","test1-app" -ScriptBlock {$env:computername}
test1-FS
test1-APP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some errors were still not catched here is the part to modify :

```
$computers=@("test1","test2","rodc1")
$computers|%{
    try{
    $s=new-PSSession -ComputerName $_
    if($s -eq $null){
        $rapport+="$_ : cant connect to host`n<br/>"
    }
    else{
        $sess+=$s
    }
    }
    catch{
        $rapport+="$_ : cant connect to host`n<br/>"
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just compare your input list and your output list :

```
Compare-Object $computers $result

InputObject SideIndicator
----------- -------------
test1     <=
test2     <=
```

or directly

```
(Compare-Object $computers $result).InputObject
```